# Spring JSP getting javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jstl

Getting the exception having following code. JSTL shows 500 with not found property (like id).

**JSP**

```
<c:forEach var="movie" items="${movies}>">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="foo"/></td>
        <td>${movie.id}</td>
        <%--<td>${movie.year}</td>--%>
        <%--<td>${movie.quality}</td>--%>
        <%--<td>${movie.size}</td>--%>
        <%--<td>${movie.created}</td>--%>
        <%--<td>${movie.seed}</td>--%>
        <%--<td>${movie.peer}</td>--%>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/moderator/upload", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showUploadPage() {

    ModelAndView uploadPage = new ModelAndView("upload");
    Movie movie = new Movie("Terminator 2", 200, "HD", 20, 24233523, 1991, "now");
    List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();
    movies.add(movie);
    uploadPage.addObject("movies", movies);
    movies.forEach(item -> LOGGER.info(item.toString()));
    return uploadPage;
}
```

Have the following output in console (SLF4J):

```
Movie{created='now', id=0, name='Terminator 2', year=1991, quality='HD', size=24233523, seed=20, peer=200}
```

Getters and Setters in the entity class

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(nullable = false)
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(nullable = false)
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

**Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table 
public class Movie implements Serializable, Torrent {

private int id;
private String name;
private int year;
private String quality;
private long size;
private String created;
private int seed;
private int peer;

public Movie() {
}

public Movie(String name, int peer, String quality, int seed, long size, int year, String created) {
    this.name = name;
    this.peer = peer;
    this.quality = quality;
    this.seed = seed;
    this.size = size;
    this.year = year;
    this.created = created;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(nullable = false)
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(nullable = false)
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Column(nullable = false)
public String getQuality() {
    return quality;
}

public void setQuality(String quality) {
    this.quality = quality;
}

@Column(nullable = false)
public long getSize() {
    return size;
}

public void setSize(long size) {
    this.size = size;
}

@Column(nullable = false)
public String getCreated() {
    return created;
}

public void setCreated(String created) {
    this.created = created;
}

@Column(nullable = false)
public int getPeer() {
    return peer;
}

public void setPeer(int peer) {
    this.peer = peer;
}


@Column(nullable = false)
public int getSeed() {
    return seed;
}

public void setSeed(int seed) {
    this.seed = seed;
}

@Column(nullable = false)
public int getYear() {
    return year;
}

public void setYear(int year) {
    this.year = year;
}


@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    Movie movie = (Movie) o;

    if (id != movie.id) return false;
    if (year != movie.year) return false;
    if (size != movie.size) return false;
    if (seed != movie.seed) return false;
    if (peer != movie.peer) return false;
    if (!name.equals(movie.name)) return false;
    if (!quality.equals(movie.quality)) return false;
    return created.equals(movie.created);

}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = id;
    result = 31 * result + name.hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + year;
    result = 31 * result + quality.hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + (int) (size ^ (size >>> 32));
    result = 31 * result + created.hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + seed;
    result = 31 * result + peer;
    return result;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Movie{" +
            "created='" + created + '\'' +
            ", id=" + id +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", year=" + year +
            ", quality='" + quality + '\'' +
            ", size=" + size +
            ", seed=" + seed +
            ", peer=" + peer +
            '}';
}
```

}

**Stacktrace**

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/upload.jsp at line 77

74:                                 <c:forEach var="movie" items="${movies}>">
75:                                     <tr>
76:                                         <td><input type="checkbox" name="foo"/></td>
77:                                         <td>${movie.id}</td>
78:                                         <%--<td>${movie.year}</td>--%>
79:                                         <%--<td>${movie.quality}</td>--%>
80:                                         <%--<td>${movie.size}</td>--%>


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:574)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1243)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:859)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    com.svitsky.filter.CharsetFilter.doFilter(CharsetFilter.java:27)
    com.svitsky.filter.ModeratorFilter.doFilter(ModeratorFilter.java:38)
root cause

javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'id' not found on type java.lang.String
    javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:268)
    javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.access$300(BeanELResolver.java:221)
    javax.el.BeanELResolver.property(BeanELResolver.java:355)
    javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:95)
    org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:110)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)
    org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:943)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.upload_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(upload_jsp.java:315)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.upload_jsp._jspService(upload_jsp.java:205)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1243)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:859)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    com.svitsky.filter.CharsetFilter.doFilter(CharsetFilter.java:27)
    com.svitsky.filter.ModeratorFilter.doFilter(ModeratorFilter.java:38)
```

Comment: show the complete object Movie and the exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is ok except for this line:

```
<c:forEach var="movie" items="${movies}>">
```

That is causing the issue, it should be

```
<c:forEach var="movie" items="${movies}">
```

typo error I guess.

Comment: No worries.  It happens sometimes :)